# Getting this error during website hosting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, hosting

I have hosted a Gen4 PTC script at http://lenasiaa.5gbfree.com configured mysql database and setup everything required. But still my site is not getting hosted. It is showing this error when trying to open...

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 13219 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /home/lenasiaa/public_html/index.php on line 4

Fatal error: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in /home/lenasiaa/public_html/index.php on line 4
```

Please help me.... what to do?

Once more my website url is http://lenasiaa.5gbfree.com

Answer (score 0):

Contact your hosting provider to disable PHP Safe mode, if that's not an option and they support custom php.ini's then add these two lines.

```
safe_mode = 0
safe_mode_gid = 1
```